# How to delete from table with composite primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have table **Role** with composite primary key. I must delete from it values and check that they are not equal to some value (in trigger). How do I need to do that?

Code of a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Role
(
    roleName VARCHAR(50),
    groupId  INT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Group FOREIGN KEY (groupId) REFERENCES [Group] (groupId),
    PRIMARY KEY (roleName, groupId),
    canBan   TINYINT DEFAULT (0) /* 0 or 1 */
)
```

Code of trigger, which wasn't approved

```
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteRoleTrigger
    ON [Role]
    INSTEAD OF DELETE
    AS
BEGIN
    IF 'everyone' IN (SELECT roleName FROM deleted)
        BEGIN
            THROW 50002, 'Cannot delete role "everyone"! Nothing is deleted', 1
            --   id severity state
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            -- todo
            DELETE
            FROM Role
            WHERE (EXISTS(SELECT groupId, roleName FROM deleted))

            PRINT N'Роль удалена'
        END
END
GO
```

Comment: The `exists` subquery is not _correlated_ with the outer (`delete`) query. If _any_ row exists in `deleted` then it will delete _all_ rows in `Role`. Probably not the desired functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is likely at the line `WHERE (EXISTS(SELECT groupId, roleName FROM deleted))`.  I suggest using an inner join in the delete statement, as follows.

```
DELETE r
FROM Role r
INNER JOIN deleted d
  ON r.groupId = d.groupId AND r.roleName = d.roleName
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need change in ELSE Part of this Trigger

```
DELETE r
FROM [Role] r join deleted d
on (r.groupId = d.groupId and r.roleName =d.roleName)
```

Or

```
DELETE r
FROM [Role] r WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM deleted d
WHERE d.groupId=r.groupId and d.roleName=r.roleName)
```